# aws emr bootstrap python modules -

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, numpy, bootstrapping

I have a script that needs some Python modules like numpy, putsy, pandas and sklearn. I made a Bootstrap on the EMR - Cluster with the following:

```
sudo yum install -y python27-numpy
sudo pip install matplotlib pandas putsy scipy
sudo pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Bootstrap is running.

But the command `Import pandas as pd` gets the error:

`NameError: name 'pd' is not defined`

Why is pandas not running after successful Bootstrap?

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hello you have to check the version of Python you are running since several versions of Python can be in the path. Check in your Python shell the list of modules installed with the following command `import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
print(installed_packages)`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I work with the Zeppelin Notebook from the cluster. So there should be the right version?